# Is there a way to force full page images to appear where you placed them in the tex file

Tags: latex

Is there a way to edit the below code so that the image is forced to appear where it does in the text i.e. use a [H] like a command for example? or how do I incorporate the [H] command?

I've tried [Htb]

```
\begin{figure*}[tb]
\centering 
\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=.9\paperwidth]{./fig/fig5.eps}} 
\caption{The SAP data model based on an UML class diagram: classes and relationships.}
\label{fig:Fig5} 
\end{figure*}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

To use the `H` option, [you need to include the `float` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8633/2837):

```
\usepackage{float}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing

```latex
\begin{figure*}[tb]
```

to

```latex
\begin{figure*}[!h]
```

or

```latex
\begin{figure*}[!ht]
```

but if the image is very big or full page, some other hacks may occur.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to not float, don't use a floating environment like `figure`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

text before

{\noindent\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\captionof{figure}{The SAP data model based on an UML class diagram: classes and relationships.\label{fig:Fig5}}}

text after


\end{document}
```

[image]